# How to output git merge failure to file

Tags: git, logging, error-handling, merge

I've setup a script to periodically rebase and merge changes in the development branch list of child branches:

```
while read -r child
do
  echo "Merging development to $child" 2>&1 >> $HOME/logs/git_rebase.log
  git checkout $child
  git status
  echo "Commencing merge" 2>&1 >> $HOME/logs/git_rebase.log

  if [[ ! $(git merge --progress -m 'merge development to child branch' --strategy-option theirs origin/development_does_not_exst 1>/dev/null 2>error.log) ]]; then
    echo "git merge for $child failed with the following log:"
    echo `git log -1`
  else
    echo "merge successful"
  fi

  #git push
done < "../branchlist.txt"
```

This project is multimodule, so any changes in development only effect one module in it. I'm not too concerned about there being conflicts due to my merge strategy; the only changes to the branches in branchlist.txt should be changes brought in from the development branch to the parent module.  However, I would like to know if this fails for any reason.  As such, I would like to output any errors to the error.log, and then email the contents of it to myself.

So far, while my if statement seems to work on detecting failures (testing with a branch that does not exist), I have not been able to redirect the console output to a log file.  Has anyone done something similar?

Comment: Does `git merge ... 2>&1 > error.log` make any difference?

Comment: I just answered my own question.  Its kind of embarrassing how simple it was.  Thank you, though.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out; it seems to be a very simple case of using `>> error.log` in the echo statements:

```
while read -r child
do
  echo "Merging development to $child" 2>&1 >> $HOME/logs/git_rebase.log
  git checkout $child
  git status
  echo "Commencing merge" 2>&1 >> $HOME/logs/git_rebase.log

  if [[ ! $(git merge --progress -m 'merge development to child branch' --strategy-option theirs origin/development_does_not_exst 1>/dev/null 2>error.log) ]]; then
    echo "git merge for $child failed with the following log:" >> $HOME/logs/error.log
    echo `git log -1` >> $HOME/logs/error.log
  else
    echo "merge successful" >> $HOME/logs/git_rebase.log
  fi

  #git push
done < "../branchlist.txt"
```